# What could happen if I plug into my Arduino an AC adapter instead of a DC one?

Tags: arduino, voltage, ac, dc

I´ve read that Arduino needs a DC adapter and not an AC one, I know that.

What could happen if I plug into my arduino an AC adapter?

I need to do a quick test with two small 4.5v DC motors, and I only have at hand an AC adapter of 12v/1.5A (the center pin is positive), and I don´t want to fry my Arduino Mega...

Comment: In an earlier question you mentioned that you intended to purchase a motor-controller add-on for your Arduino. If you use that correctly, you don't need to worry about some of the problems in Anindo's answer. You may find it helpful to buy a cheap multimeter (never use cheap multimeters on anything connected to a wall power socket) and find some introduction to hobby electronics (a book or a website - Use google).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming what you have is actually an adapter that outputs AC, this is what will happen:

- The Arduino will fry: It does not have a bridge rectifier on board. The reversed half-cycle will destroy the board.
- The motors won't work either, because, as you noted, they are **DC** motors.

However, as an AC output does not have a "*center pin is positive*", given that they are **AC**, it is quite likely that you have a **AC to DC** adapter. You will most probably just suffer from fried motor syndrome - 4.5 Volt motors can smell quite delicious when powered by 12 Volts - especially after the sizzling stops.

---

**Other caveats**: If you are planning to drive those 4.5 Volt motors directly off GPIO pins on the Arduino board, your Arduino will be toast anyway, for these reasons:

- The GPIO pins should not be used to drive more than approximately 20-30 mA current per pin (*the official rating is 40 mA per GPIO, absolute maximum*), else overheating and thermal death ensues. Those motors need to be really tiny ones that operate at say 10 milliamperes or less - even tiny pager motors need more, though specialty micro-motors rated below 10 mA do exist.
- The Arduino pins cannot handle the back-EMF the motors will generate, so the microcontroller will die  ... permanently.
- The voltage regulator on the Arduino will heat up horribly and may either thermal-shutdown or be destroyed if the motor's current drawn is significantly more than around 150 mA, even if you drive the motors directly from the +5V pin on the Arduino, ignoring the GPIO pins. The on-board regulator is a linear regulator, so heat generated is `(12 - 5) x current`. Any non-trivial current, i.e. the motor's load, will generate a lot of heat at the regulator.

---

**Edit:** In response to comment providing image of adapter:

[image]

Notice the brightened line of text, which specifies the output of the adapter. The symbol circled in red indicates DC output.

The tilde `~` symbol directly above it indicates AC, i.e. the *input* is AC, hence the term *AC adapter*.

If the output had been AC, the same tilde symbol would be used in the output line as well.

Comment: +1 for *AC output does not have a "center pin is positive"*.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This is my adaptor, and it clearly says AC, but it also says that the center pin is positive: http://postimg.org/image/ug87tg2w1/

Comment: It says the output is 12Vdc.

Comment: Again, many thanks for your kind reply! So, I can safely assume that it can be used with an arduino! :)

Comment: @RosamundaRosamunda You can use that adapter safely with an Arduino. Whether you can safely use the Arduino with that motor, would depend on the *Caveats* section of my answer. If you get fireworks, please do post images for us!

Comment: Yes, thanks! I´ve connected the motors using an H-Bridge, so I think I can use them safely. ´BTW, I´ve followed the instructions here (http://hardwarefun.com/tutorials/controlling-speed-of-dc-motors-using-arduino), and they move, but very slowly, due to lack of power. This is how I have them connected: http://hardwarefun.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/basic-bot.png. Again, many, many thanks!!

Comment: One thing about feeding 12V (DC) into the Ardiuno power jack - your onboard 5v regulator is going to get HOT if you use it for a while. See other threads here about the excess voltage being turned to heat. Safer and cooler to either (a) regulate separately and feed the 5v pin; or (b) get a 7.5v AC/DC adapter that will reduce the Arduino's regulator work/heat dissipation.

Comment: @RonJ. Not really - the Arduino doesn't consume much power (not counting peripherals like the motors mentioned). 7 Volts across a typical 50 mA (*I just checked mine while running a massive code loop*) = 350 mW. Warm regulator, yes, but not too hot to touch.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh I've just put a Mega together with a just few sensors. Plugged in a 12v and nearly burnt my finger on the onboard regulator! Switched to a 7.5v adapter and its warm now but runs normally even with the ethernet shield plugged in. Believe me, it does get hotter 'n hell at 12V!

Comment: @RonJ. Your sensors, what current draw each? I have Arduinos (no sensors, no LED output) that have been running 24-7 for months off a single 12 Volt switching lab supply. Perhaps my fingertips are not as sensitive as yours? ... Or hell is a lower temperature reference in colder climates :-)

Comment: @AnindoGhosh ironically, a DHT11 temp sensor, RTC, at least one IR (either PIR or distance, I forget), oh yes an LCD shield with a ~2k backlight dimming resistor. Testing was done via USB and it didn't heat at all (obviously didn't go thru the regulator) and had to be under the USB limit - the first test with an external 12V was thermally scary. Dropping to 7.5V cooled things down. The DHT11 that was supposed to monitor outside temp is now monitoring INSIDE the project box temp, avg 90*F. The OP did want to run a shield with his Mega.

Comment: @RonJ. Ahh, OK, I see where your situation differs from mine and therefore temperature at regulator might be so high.